# I am using a RFID reader module MFRC522 with my raspberry pi but it is not working with python 3

Tags: raspbian, python, rpi.gpio, spi, python-3

I am using RFID reader module (MFRC522) with my raspberry pi and when I run the script with python 2 it works fine and reads the RFID tag but when I run it with python3 I get an error - No Module named 'spi'

My script is -

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import SimpleMFRC522
reader = SimpleMFRC522.SimpleMFRC522()
try:
        id,text = reader.read()
        print(text)
finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

I need this to run with python3 because I am using Firebase in my project and it works with python3, not python2.7

Comment: have you tried installing SPI? `pip3 install spi`?

Comment: Or you forgot the statement  "import spidev".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the official package for the MFRC522 module was written in python2 and hence causing the issue.
I found an updated package by a user on github and it works fine now. 
[Github Link to the package](https://github.com/barni2000/MFRC522-python3/)