# RFID and LED Script disables RFID reader until reboot

Tags: gpio, python, pi-2, led, rfid

I have two simple scripts, which work individually. One simply lights an LED, the other reads RFID. Now I want to put them together, but seem to fail.

Once this runs, I can't read RFID anymore until I restart my Raspberry. Both functions work as intended, if I comment out the respectively other code (LED and RFID).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522

# RFID setup
reader = SimpleMFRC522() #GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

# LED setup
rl=37
gl=35
bl=33
freq=100
GPIO.setup(rl, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(gl, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(bl, GPIO.OUT)

r=GPIO.PWM(rl,freq)
g=GPIO.PWM(gl,freq)
b=GPIO.PWM(bl,freq)
r.start(0)
g.start(0)
b.start(0)

GPIO.cleanup()

# Set LED to R, G, B for TIME seconds
def led(rv,gv,bv,t):
    r.ChangeDutyCycle(rv)
    g.ChangeDutyCycle(gv)
    b.ChangeDutyCycle(bv)
    time.sleep(t)
    r.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
    g.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
    b.ChangeDutyCycle(0)


while True:
    try:
        print("Reading..")
        id, text = reader.read()
        print(id)
        print(text)
        if text == "test":
            print('READ TEST. LED GREEN NOW.')
            led(0,2,0,1)
        else:
            print('DIDN\'T READ TEST. LED RED NOW.')
            led(2,0,0,1)
        time.sleep(1)

    finally:
        print('Loop done.')
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

In an endless loop, I read RFID, if the text "test" is read, the LED is green, if not it's red.

Why does the LED and RFID function interfere so badly? How can I change the code to achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: Remove your GPIO.cleanup() lines, this would normally only be called before you exit a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your GPIO.cleanup() lines, this would normally only be called before you exit a program.

https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/

> **Cleanup**
>
> At the end any program, it is good practice to clean up any resources
>   you might have used. This is no different with RPi.GPIO. By returning
>   all channels you have used back to inputs with no pull up/down, you
>   can avoid accidental damage to your RPi by shorting out the pins. Note
>   that this will only clean up GPIO channels that your script has used.
>   Note that GPIO.cleanup() also clears the pin numbering system in use.
>
> To clean up at the end of your script:
>
> GPIO.cleanup()
>
> It is possible that don't want to clean up every channel leaving some
>   set up when your program exits. You can clean up individual channels,
>   a list or a tuple of channels:
>
> GPIO.cleanup(channel)
>
> GPIO.cleanup( (channel1, channel2) )
>
> GPIO.cleanup( [channel1, channel2] )