# Reading ISO15693 SLIX2 18000-3-1 RFID tags with Raspberry Pi

Tags: rfid

There are Raspberry Pi components like RC522 that can read NFC tags, and it only supports ISO/IEC 14443 A/MIFARE and NTAG. We can't use those.

We are looking for a component that can read international library standard RFID tags that are **ISO 15693** HF tags (13,56MHz), and are **read mostly from roughly 30 centimeters up to 1 meter away** from the tag. The device we are after for would be used to take inventory of hundreds of thousands of library items by scanning the item numbers from their RFID tags and comparing the collected lists with the lists given by our ILS (integrated library system), or by searching specific given item numbers from the collection to find missing items. It could also be used to create smart shelves that transmit data to info screens about items that are recently returned and available in the shelves that contain returned books, movies etc.

Of course there are commercial products costing over thousand euros for these purposes, but we would also like to take our chances creating our own gadgets.

What kind of RFID tag reading component we should be looking for Raspberry Pi? Is there any for our purposes?

Thank You very much for your kind answers.

Comment: Perhaps you can try those a little bit cheaper, US$500 starter kits: References:
(1) "HF 13.56 MHZ STARTER'S KIT - RfidInc US$500": 
https://www.rfidinc.com/hf-13-56-mhz-starter-s-kit,

(2) "ISO 15693 HF RFID Tag for Library Management - Electronic Specifier 2011feb21":
https://www.electronicspecifier.com/industries/wm/iso-15693-hf-rfid-tag-for-library-management. Rpi knows UART, I2C, and SPI.  So no problem for readers speaking these languages.

Comment: BTW, 1meter reader should be very expensive.  The Rpi toy readers can only do a couple of centimetres at most.  Perhaps you can DIY one with very big coils. Sound like a good college level EE/IT projects. I often visit Cornell Uni EE course's low budget Rpi  group projects for ideas   :)