# Ubuntu 20.10 and GPIO

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio, python-3, ubuntu

I have trouble installing RPi.GPIO library on Ubuntu 20.10. I run `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` then `apt-get install python python3 python3-pip python3-dev` everything went ok. Then I run `pip install RPi.GPIO` and get a lot of errors.

```
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for RPi.GPIO
  Running setup.py clean for RPi.GPIO
Failed to build RPi.GPIO
Installing collected packages: RPi.GPIO
    Running setup.py install for RPi.GPIO ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-vtnsv0d4/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.8/RPi.GPIO
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/
    Complete output (85 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/RPi
    copying RPi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/RPi
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/RPi/GPIO
    copying RPi/GPIO/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/RPi/GPIO
    running build_ext
    building 'RPi._GPIO' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8
    creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c source/py_gpio.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c source/c_gpio.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/c_gpio.o
    source/c_gpio.c: In function ‘setup’:
    source/c_gpio.c:130:9: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
      130 |     if ((uint32_t)gpio_mem % PAGE_SIZE)
          |         ^
    source/c_gpio.c:131:34: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
      131 |         gpio_mem += PAGE_SIZE - ((uint32_t)gpio_mem % PAGE_SIZE);
          |                                  ^
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c source/cpuinfo.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/cpuinfo.o
    source/cpuinfo.c: In function ‘get_rpi_info’:
    source/cpuinfo.c:139:28: warning: format ‘%llx’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘uint64_t *’ {aka ‘long unsigned int *’} [-Wformat=]
      139 |       sscanf(revision, "%llx", &rev);
          |                         ~~~^   ~~~~
          |                            |   |
          |                            |   uint64_t * {aka long unsigned int *}
          |                            long long unsigned int *
          |                         %lx
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c source/event_gpio.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/event_gpio.o
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c source/soft_pwm.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/soft_pwm.o
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c source/py_pwm.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_pwm.o
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c source/common.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/common.o
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c source/constants.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/c_gpio.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/cpuinfo.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/event_gpio.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/soft_pwm.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_pwm.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/common.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/RPi/_GPIO.cpython-38-aarch64-linux-gnu.so
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/soft_pwm.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/soft_pwm.c:28: multiple definition of `threads'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/event_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/event_gpio.c:60: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_pwm.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:38: multiple definition of `gpio_direction'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:38: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_pwm.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/py_pwm.h:23: multiple definition of `PWMType'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/py_pwm.h:23: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_pwm.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:41: multiple definition of `module_setup'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:41: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_pwm.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:40: multiple definition of `setup_error'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:40: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_pwm.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:39: multiple definition of `rpiinfo'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:39: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_pwm.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:37: multiple definition of `pin_to_gpio'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:37: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_pwm.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:36: multiple definition of `pin_to_gpio_rev3'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:36: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_pwm.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:35: multiple definition of `pin_to_gpio_rev2'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:35: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_pwm.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:34: multiple definition of `pin_to_gpio_rev1'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:34: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_pwm.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:33: multiple definition of `gpio_mode'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:33: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/common.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:40: multiple definition of `setup_error'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:40: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/common.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:41: multiple definition of `module_setup'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:41: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/common.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:33: multiple definition of `gpio_mode'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:33: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/common.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:37: multiple definition of `pin_to_gpio'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:37: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/common.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:39: multiple definition of `rpiinfo'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:39: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/common.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:38: multiple definition of `gpio_direction'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:38: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/common.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:36: multiple definition of `pin_to_gpio_rev3'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:36: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/common.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:35: multiple definition of `pin_to_gpio_rev2'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:35: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/common.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:34: multiple definition of `pin_to_gpio_rev1'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:34: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:26: multiple definition of `high'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:26: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:27: multiple definition of `low'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:27: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:29: multiple definition of `output'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:29: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:28: multiple definition of `input'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:28: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:30: multiple definition of `pwm'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:30: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:31: multiple definition of `serial'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:31: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:32: multiple definition of `i2c'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:32: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:33: multiple definition of `spi'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:33: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:34: multiple definition of `unknown'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:34: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:35: multiple definition of `board'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:35: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:36: multiple definition of `bcm'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:36: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:37: multiple definition of `pud_off'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:37: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:38: multiple definition of `pud_up'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:38: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:39: multiple definition of `pud_down'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:39: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:40: multiple definition of `rising_edge'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:40: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:41: multiple definition of `falling_edge'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:41: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:42: multiple definition of `both_edge'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/constants.h:42: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:41: multiple definition of `module_setup'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:41: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:40: multiple definition of `setup_error'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:40: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:39: multiple definition of `rpiinfo'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:39: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:38: multiple definition of `gpio_direction'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:38: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:37: multiple definition of `pin_to_gpio'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:37: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:36: multiple definition of `pin_to_gpio_rev3'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:36: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:35: multiple definition of `pin_to_gpio_rev2'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:35: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:34: multiple definition of `pin_to_gpio_rev1'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:34: first defined here
    /usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:33: multiple definition of `gpio_mode'; build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/source/common.h:33: first defined here
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-sa5epryd/RPi.GPIO/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-vtnsv0d4/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.8/RPi.GPIO Check the logs for full command output.
```

And I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the pip3 install RPi.gpio with this:

```
export CFLAGS=-fcommon

pip3 install RPi.GPIO
```

Source: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=289084

Answer (score 0):

Rather than the rather bizarre steps you followed, most of which are unnecessary and possibly damaging I suggest you restore a clean Ubuntu and utilise the included Python.

Then download the official tarball https://pypi.org/project/RPi.GPIO/#files

Then follow the **instructions included**, viz.

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev

To install the module:

$ sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Alternatively you could use my enhanced [Pi.GPIO](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117593/8697)

PS I have used neither on Ubuntu or a 64bit OS, and there may be issues with integer size which would require attention.