# How can I query pull state of GPIO pin?

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio

I am writing a script that should query if an input pin is configured as pull-up or pull-down using the RPi.GPIO package.

When configuring each output I can call

```
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
  # or
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
```

This is done by user input at runtime. After that my application needs to check if the user configured everything properly (one can never be sure!).
Is there anything like `GPIO.gpio_function(pin)` but that will output the pull state of the input?
(It would be a plus if it also returned the initial state of an output.)

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to determine the pull state of GPIO on most Pi (except by measurement).

It is possible with the BCM2711 used by Pi4 and I have written a Python3 library (based on RPi.GPIO) which does this and a program gpioread which shows this and the actual programmed function/state.

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117593/8697

Corrupted git repository fixed. This can be downloaded

```
git clone https://github.com/Milliways2/Pi.GPIO.git
```

And installed with

```
sudo apt install python-dev python3-dev
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

NOTE you can also get pull using the raspi-gpio utility.

Comment: Thank you @Milliways for your answer and package suggestion. I tried installing it but when I execute `sudo python3 setup.py build` I get the `error: package directory 'Pi' does not exist`. Is there a step I'm missing? Thanks once more!

Comment: @tron_ccp My apologies. 
The original git file got corrupted and lost its directory structure. It should now be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't query the pull state with RPi.GPIO.

In fact you can only query the pulls in software in the latest Pi models based on the BCM2711.  I'm not sure if any of the mainstream GPIO libraries actually provide support for doing so.