# Keeping a Python script for PWM running and just changing duty cycle

Tags: gpio, python, pwm, bash

I am currently trying to connect a laser to my 3D printer and give a TTL signal manipulated by an M106 command.

The "official" way didn't work out for me so right now I am trying to control it by my Raspberry Pi 3B+ with Octoprint on it. I am using a plugin called Fan Speed Mirror to transform the Fan Speed (M106) to a PWM signal on a GPIO pin.

Therefore I have copied this bash script, which is calling the python script and giving it the M106 number (at least I think that's what it does, please note that I know only basic programming stuff and near to nothing about python or bash).

fan.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
killall fan.py
echo $1 $2 $3 >>/home/pi/fan.txt
python /home/pi/fan.py $1
exit $?
```

fan.py script:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)

s = int(sys.argv[1])
dc = s*100/255

p = GPIO.PWM(11,1000) # channel=11 frequency=1kHz
p.start(dc)

time.sleep(100000000000000000000)
```

As you can see I am trying to run the PWM signal as long as no new M106 command is entered.

But that's not really working out.

**Instead it runs the first M106 command and then stops the gcode.**

I already asked the developer of the plugin here: https://github.com/b-morgan/OctoPrint-FanSpeedMirror/issues/3

But I was hoping to get some input here as well. I hope that what I am trying to achieve is even possible.

Comment: what is your specific question?

Comment: What is a M106 command?

Comment: **Why** use a bash script to run a python script. Python is a scripting language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I was going to do this I would use hardware PWM which continues to run after the program exits.

Hardware PWM is available in my [Pi.GPIO](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117593/8697) (which is a superset of RPi.GPIO). It is also available in `pigpio`

The following modification to your program should work (I have not tested it) and avoid the strange sleep and need to kill processes, although it is rather inelegant.

Call directly - DO NOT use any scripts.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
from signal import pause
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

s = int(sys.argv[1])
dc = s*100/255

p = GPIO.PWM(11,1000) # channel=11 frequency=1kHz
p.start(dc)

pause()
```

PS You should not get into the bad habit of using GPIO.BOARD - use BCM numbers like practically every other program.

NOTE RPi.GPIO PWM is software timed and imprecise - it is more suitable for dimming LEDs, whether this matters depends on your hardware.

Comment: I copied your script and tried to call it directly but that didn't work somehow. But then I called it by using the batch script with the added '&' as joan suggested and now it works perfectly as intended. Thank you both very much!!

Answer (score 0):

If I guess properly at the question it may be solved by changing

`python /home/pi/fan.py $1`

to

`python /home/pi/fan.py $1 &`