# How to create a data signal using pwm from a gpio output?

Tags: gpio, pwm

I'm a new member of the raspberry pi community and I have problems with starting my first project.
I want to be able to create a data signal using pulse width modulation with the gpio headers. The duty cycle would determine the value of a bit. so for example 75% duty cycle would represent a 1 and a 25% duty cycle would represent a 0. So I have to be able to control the amplitude of the signal very precicely since I want the frequency of the signal to be around 10000 hertz.
The data signal would be used to control a LED strip.
I want to write the software from the ground up. How would one go about this? I know python and a little bit of c++.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Choose a GPIO library.

See https://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Code_Samples

Write the code.

Answer (score 0):

"I want to write the software from the ground up."

1. Read the Peripheral documentation
   https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/processors.html
2. Choose a language
3. Write the code.

"I have problems with starting my first project."
There are a few caveats; I would NOT start with PWM which is involved and has limited support.

You might like to read the survey of available libraries I wrote a couple of years ago https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117592/8697