# How to selectively read Mifare blocks with an NFC reader?

Tags: python, nfc

I want to use a RPi combined with a [RC522 NFC reader](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MFRC522.pdf) to make a Mifare card-based authentication system<sup>(1)</sup>. I am struggling with the capacity to read selected blocks of data on the NFC card.

I have been using information and code from [PiMyLifeUp](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-rfid-rc522/) to read and write data on NFC cards. It works great.

I see however that this is limited to reading (not writing) the UID and reading and writing to block 8. I almost thought that I had the remaining of the information from a [detailed answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/110791/6123) but it stops short at what I did (and uses the same code).

My question: how to read and write any block?

---

<sup>(1)</sup> I initially intended to use an Arduino but even my limited initial tests show that the RPi is much more reliable in reading and writing the cards

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that SimpleMFRC522.py [defines](https://github.com/pimylifeup/MFRC522-python/blob/master/mfrc522/SimpleMFRC522.py#L11C3-L11C27) the blocks to read and write:

```py
BLOCK_ADDRS = [8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Congratulations on answering - all on your own!  One suggestion: You should click the "Accept" mark on your answer when you're able (may take a day or two??). That will signal others that this answer worked for you. Note that you can't **upvote** your answer (or your Q), but you can **accept** it.